# Issuing kill through subprocess

Tags: shell, subprocess, kill

I am trying to write a simple python server that runs and kills another python script. The problem I am having is that the kill command gets issued without error but doesn't kill the process. I have tried manually with 'kill -INT pid' without any result.

The command works in shell but not python. I am doing a 'soft' kill because the script controls a light and a 'kill -9' doesn't turn off the light.

NOTE: the script is running on yocto-distr

```
import socket, subprocess

srv = socket.socket()
srv.bind(('', 1340))
srv.listen(3)
while 1:
    connection, address = srv.accept()
    data = int(connection.recv(1024))
    if data == 0:
        ps_id = subprocess.check_output('ps|grep python\ /home/root/python/backlight_mod.py', shell=True)
        ps_id = ps_id.split(' ')[2]
        subprocess.call('kill -INT ' + str(ps_id), shell=True)
        print 'Terminated'
    elif data == 1:
        subprocess.call('python ~/python/backlight_mod.py &', shell=True)
    connection.close()
```

The output from 'kill -l':

```
HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM STKFLT CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH IO PWR SYS RTMIN RTMIN+1 RTMIN+2 RTMIN+3 RTMIN+4 RTMIN+5 RTMIN+6 RTMIN+7 RTMIN+8 RTMIN+9 RTMIN+10 RTMIN+11 RTMIN+12 RTMIN+13 RTMIN+14 RTMIN+15 RTMAX-14 RTMAX-13 RTMAX-12 RTMAX-11 RTMAX-10 RTMAX-9 RTMAX-8 RTMAX-7 RTMAX-6 RTMAX-5 RTMAX-4 RTMAX-3 RTMAX-2 RTMAX-1 RTMAX
```

Comment: You should check the raw output of `ps` to ensure that it's actually listing the requested process, and use [`os.kill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill) to terminate the process rather than spawning another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider os.kill as suggested by @Petesh so your code would look something like this:

```
if data == 0:
    ps_id = subprocess.check_output('ps|grep python\ /home/root/python/backlight_mod.py', shell=True)
    ps_id = ps_id.split(' ')[2] 
    os.kill(pid, 3)
    print 'Terminated'
```

Also consider the following to extract pid:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

for process in out.splitlines():
  if 'backlight_mod.py' in process:
    pid = int(process.split(None, 1)[0])
    os.kill(pid, 3)
```